# Projection in JPQL with property of type list

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How I can made a select of a property of type list on JPQL? 
example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String birthdate;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Phone> getPhones();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Phone {

    @id
    private Long id;
    private String number;

    ...
}
```

And on repository I want a projection, so:

```
public interface IPersonProjection {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
    List<Phone> phones();
}




@Repository
public interface IAtendimentoRepository extends JpaRepository<Atendimento, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT P.id, P.name, P.phones FROM Person P ")
    List<IPersonProjection> findAllProjected();
}
```

But when I try this (SELECT P.id, P.name, P.phones FROM Person P) occur an error on syntax of SQL.

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [`Spring Data Docs`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), you should have accessors of your properties in your `Projection Interface`. So i think you should change the name of `phones` method of `IPersonProjection` to `getPhones`.

Comment: Oh, I've wrote the code wrong. But I already changed the code. However, it's still the same error. On the console it's showed that there's an error on sql mysql and when I remove P.phones it's work.