# How do you do a subquery in a projection?

Tags: java, jpa

I am using Spring-Data-JPA and I have a projection but I want one of the parameters to be a list.

I tried writing the following JPQL query:

```
select new app.HeaderProjection(
  p.businessReference, 
  p.name, (
    select l 
    from LocalizedString l 
    where 
      p.id = l.programId and
      p.name.keyHash = l.keyHash
  )) 
from Program p
```

I get (formatted for readability)

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [app.HeaderProjection].
Expected arguments are: 
  app.BusinessReference, 
  app.Localized, 
  app.ProgramLocalizedString
```

The last parameter looks weird in that I am expecting it to be a list rather than a single object.

Similar to [Projection in JPQL with property of type list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558663/projection-in-jpql-with-property-of-type-list) but using a subquery.

So far the only way I can think about getting around this is to make a project that joins reference, name and optional localized strings one localized string at a time, then create new objects by iterating through that collection.

```
select new app.HeaderProjection(
  p.businessReference, 
  p.name,
  l 
) 
from Program p
  left join LocalizedString l
    on
      p.id = l.programId and
      p.name.keyHash = l.keyHash
```

Comment: Just realized this was a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558663/projection-in-jpql-with-property-of-type-list (though the question evolved into this as I was trying out to see what went wrong).

Comment: Actually it is slightly different (my scenario has a subquery from another object)